# ldapsearch works but python-ldap doesn't

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

The following works and returns a list of all users

```
ldapsearch -x -b "ou=lunchbox,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com" -D "OFFICE\Administrator" -h ad.office.lbox.com -p 389 -W "(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user))"
```

I'm trying to do the same in Python and I'm getting `Invalid credentials`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ldap

dn = "cn=Administrator,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"
pw = "**password**"

con = ldap.initialize('ldap://ad.office.lbox.com')
con.simple_bind_s( dn, pw )

base_dn = 'ou=lunchbox,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com'
filter = '(objectclass=person)'
attrs = ['sn']

con.search_s( base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs )
```

Any suggestions to make this work would be great. I'm trying to learn `python-ldap` Thanks

EDIT

This is the full error I get:

```
`ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}`
```

The `LDAP` server is an Active Directory on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: are you getting an error back? is there something in you ldap logs?

Comment: @DonQuestion I've added the full error to question. Nothing in the Active Directory logs. I didn't think to mention that I'm connecting to an AD on Win2008 R2.

Comment: seems like you have a problem with the authentication. I guess it balks in the bind method?! take a look at http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-configuring-the-python-ldap-library-and-binding-to-an-ldap-directory

Comment: Yea I'm hoping someone can tell me why the `python-ldap` bind is any different then the `ldapsearch` bind.

Comment: Have you tried authenticating with just "cn=Administrator" or "Administrator"?

Comment: there's no difference. You authenticate differently, that's all

Comment: Yea @DonQuestion is right. I'm just struggling to understand how the `bind` works.

Comment: Hello @DavidNeudorfer, have you found the solution to your issue? I am running in the exact same wall...

Comment: I haven't. Please post back here if you find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using different credentials for the bind from the command line and the python script.

The command line is using the bind dn of `OFFICE\Administrator` while the script is using the bind dn of `cn=Administrator,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com`

On Active Directory, the built-in account `Administrator` doesn't reside at the top-level of the `AD` forest, it typically resides under at least the `Users` `OU`, so the dn you *probably* should be using is: `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com`.

The easiest way to find the proper entry for the user is to actually use account name in a search from the command line e.g.

```
ldapsearch -x -b "ou=lunchbox,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com" -D "OFFICE\Administrator" -h ad.office.lbox.com -p 389 -W '(samaccountname=Administrator)' dn
```

and use the `dn` returned from the command line query in your python code as the `dn` for the bind.

Answer (score 0):

The python-ldap library does not parse the user name, neither does ldapsearch. In you code, simply use the same username `OFFICE\Administrator` and let Active Directory handle it.

Also it is not uncommon for ActiveDirectory to refuse simple bind over ldap. You must use LDAPS. Add this line to bypass certificat checking:

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
```

So the whole code might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ldap

dn = "OFFICE\Administrator"
pw = "**password**"

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)

con = ldap.initialize('ldaps://ad.office.lbox.com')
con.simple_bind_s( dn, pw )

base_dn = 'ou=lunchbox,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com'
filter = '(objectclass=person)'
attrs = ['sn']

con.search_s( base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs )
```